# Deserializing yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ DateTime format using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a JSON with DateTime field which I deserialize using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, and it is working as expected except when I use `yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ` `DateTime` format which is one of the [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

According to the documentation of `IsoDateTimeConverter`:

> Converts a  to and from the ISO 8601
> date format (e.g. "2008-04-12T12:53Z").

So why this code:

```
var serializeSettings=new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializeSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());
var result= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployementHistory>(json,serializeSettings);
```

is throwing the following exception:

> {System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid
> DateTime.    at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s,
> DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)    at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader
> reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer
> serializer)

My Model:

```
public class EmployementHistory
{
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public DateTime PositionChangeDate { get; set; }
}
```

Json Example:

> { "employeename":"Tom", "PositionChangeDate":"20180710T135034Z" }

Comment: Can you show us the `MyClass` object and the JSON string you're trying to convert?

Comment: question is updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [official documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm), the `IsoDateTimeConverter` has a public property called `DateTimeFormat` where you can set your own format -
so all you need to do is supply that format:

```
var serializeSettings=new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializeSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter() {DateTimeFormat = "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"});
var result= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json,serializeSettings);
```

Comment: My expectation is IsoDateTimeConverter should support all ISO8601 formats by default.

Comment: Well, Json.Net is on gitHub, you can probably add an issue about it there, or a pull request...

Comment: did that, https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1764 thank you

Comment: Glad to help :-)